# Please (no longer) downvote this post

Tags: discussion

Well, not *this* post, but rather *[this](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3904/6307)* post.

It was created to promote the recent moderator election. Now that the election is over we don't want to see the ad anymore. However, so that it may be reused in the future, we don't want to delete the post.

Please help keep this below the 6 vote threshold!

Comment: Thanks for this. I already downvoted right after that glorious election ;-) , but others have to do so too.

Comment: Also kind of cool they place a proofing shadow behind icons such that even white RGB 0,0,0 squares show up haha

Comment: @AliceD I too downvoted right after the election (all hail our glorious leaders), but anotherHomoSapien brought up in chat that it was appearing again, so someone must have upvoted. This should hopefully serve as a bumpable reminder to keep it down.

Comment: This ad could be modified to remove the "Community moderator elections" and it would be meanful to urge voting on the questions instead.

Comment: Just FYI: this post was originally from the 2017 election cycle. It's now been updated to address this (2019) year's election promotion ad.

Comment: Also, @canadianer is a bully. (I've never seen such blatant downvote targeting!!!) ;p

Comment: @theforestecologist You deserve for posting such blatantly irrelevant advertisements!

Comment: [https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/](https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/sad-dog-madame-eyebrows-english-bulldog-10-5ac60dfcf01b4__700.gif)

Comment: Success! The community again downvotes on command.

Comment: It did work well. Maybe I should try this same technique when someone posts a better answer than me.